# present a modal view from a modal view currently presented

Tags: iphone

I need to implement kind of a chain of modal view,
in which a modal view is called from a modal view currently presented.
I believe I have implemented everything right,
but it crashes.

Is it a feasible idea?

this is how I'm calling the second modal view from the first modal view

```
hofButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
hofButton.frame = CGRectMake(700.0, 450.0, 300.0, 200.0);
[hofButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showHOF:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



-(void)showHof{
    modalHallOfFame = [[hallOfFame alloc] init];
modalHallOfFame.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:modalHallOfFame animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.

Comment: In the code your @selector argument does not match your method name. The capitalisation is different and in the @selector argument you specify the method takes an argument. If you fix this, does it still crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
You actually can call a modal view from a modal view.
What's wrong with my code above was that I had to declare showHof as
-(void)showHOF:(id)sender{
...
}

Answer (score 1):

I just did some quick testing.  It seems to work just fine.  If you posted the code that you use to present and dismiss the view controllers and the crash message you are getting that would help.